# Datepicker, same code, different localization chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datepicker

I am using datepicker with localization.

It all works great but i have a problem.

```
var selected_date = jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
selected_date = new Date(selected_date);
```

**Output on Chrome :**

```
Wed Oct 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

**Output on IE 11 :**

```
Wed Oct 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Summer Time)
```

How is that possible happening in same server, same time and same conditions.

Comment: GTB is just a synonym used by Microsoft for Eastern European Time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time